# how to start bho(browser helper objects) programming

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com, bho

I need to develop a bho, but I never use it before. So can anyone give me some advices on how to start bho? Some tutorials are welcomed. PS: I am familiar with C++ developing.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some samples:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/a7900d83-572f-4781-a0c4-41ea39710d31/

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/com/bho.html

hope it help