# IE extension - COM type in a DLL - what interfaces do I need to implement?

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, dll, com

I am trying to write an extension for Internet Explorer in C++. I find the documentation on this disparate, out-dated and generally non-comprehensive when I can find something. So I'd like to clear up exactly how one goes about writing an IE extension.

As I understand it, the extension is what's called a Browser Helper Object. This is a COM object that will be packaged into a DLL. I've come across the interfaces IObjectWithSite and IUnknown, and also the DLL-standard functions such as DllGetClassObject. Which ones do I have to implement? My guess is the following but I can't find anything solid on this:

(1) I must implement IObjectWithSite to allow IE and my BHO to communicate. 
(2) I must also implement IUnknown as IE extensions are COM types.

And I'm not sure if I really do need to implement the Dll methods at all.

Comment: Work from samples to learn the lay of the land.  Don't expect to master COM programming in a few weeks, documentation tends to be hard to read if you don't know the basics yet.  Same question [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331890/how-to-start-bhobrowser-helper-objects-programming).

Comment: The 2nd link is an example of what I mean. It states that "In terms of COM, a BHO is only required to implement IObjectWithSite". Yet it then goes on to also implement IUnknown. I'm looking for clarity on exactly what is required.

Comment: Well, sure, IObjectWithSite inherits IUnknown so a class that implements it must implement both interfaces.  One of those very basic COM details you need learn.